# Is it possible to dynamically inject templates in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've got some (well, actually a whole lot) inline templates that all look alike that I'd rather not hard code. Is it possible to inject them dynamically somehow?

For example instead of:

```
__END__

@@view1
==slim :defaultview

@@view2
==slim :defaultview

...
```

I'd like to do something like...

```
%w[view1 view2].map{|v| templates[v] = "==slim :defaultview"} #templates would be Sinatra's internal template cache
```

Comment: Maybe I'm completely misreading your question, but if you have similar code, it sounds like partials is what you want:  http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#partials

Comment: @CDub I'm afraid you are. @@defaultview (not seen in my example code above) is my partial that I'd like to use in scores of other views only instead of typing them all in the data section I'd like to iterate an array and set this template value in the code. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use [named templates](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Named%20Templates):

```
%w[view1 view2].map(&:to_sym)
               .each do |v|
  template v do
    "==slim :defaultview"
  end
end
```

If that's all each template does though, then I'm not sure why you'd create a template to wrap around the partial?